# ggplot with hebrew labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to show [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) in `R` [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) while the x-axis is **Hebrew**.
My code:

```
#server
shinyServer(  
  function(input, output, session) { 
    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      temp<-data.frame(x=c("ראשון","שני","שלישי"),y=c(1,2,3))
      ggplot(temp, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() 
    })
  })

#ui
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(), 
    mainPanel("main panel", 
      plotOutput('Plot'))
  )
))
```

The plot that I am getting is:
[image]

The letters in x-axis are ordered wrongly.

The same plot outside `shiny` works with no problems.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: It works fine on my end without any adjustments... Maybe add `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` to the beginning of the script?

Comment: I have tried that too, it didn't solve it

Comment: i cant finish it now, but i arrived here: `ord = 3:1; ggplot(temp, aes(x = x, y = y[ord])) + geom_point() + scale_x_discrete(limits = temp$x[ord])`. It produces the desired result, but I didnt match the logic, since `order(temp$x)` is `1 3 2`,...but maybe it is a good starting Point for somebody else,...